# as3 | Flash | understanding better the meaning of importing a video to flash

Tags: actionscript-3, video, import, video-streaming, flash-cs5

I am making a project, that includes many videos. In short: let's say I want to put 20 videos that are on the screen (I won't put them all together - they would be 4 together each on 5 pages for example) and the user could hear 15 seconds of them and then decide if he/she wants to play the whole video.

this is the general code I use for import (just to understand how I import):

```
    playlistVideoDisplay[i].movie = new FLVPlayback();
    playlistVideoDisplay[i].movie.load("videos/somefile.flv");
```

To my understanding - It would be easier for flash to load 20 videos of 15 seconds each - and then when a user request a specific video - flash will load the full video of this specific short one.

**BUT** - I would much rather use the other way - loading full-length (let's say 10/7/5 minutes) and when the user can play the 15 second sample and, if he/she wishes, he will play the full video (without re-loading a new video - and not making a smooth transform between the short one and the long one).

**My question is:** Am I wrong by assuming that importing bigger movies would make everything hard and slow on flash?

Answer (score 0):

First of: you'd probably do your users a great favor by NOT importing the full length FLV:s. In the case of 20 5-minute videos you'd be importing 100 minutes of moving pictures. That's a lot. For someone surfing with limited bandwidth (say a mobile broadband) that could easily eat a big chunk of the monthly allocated bandwidth.

For that reason alone, I'd say go with the small previews.

Having said that, I'd recommend you have a look at this class: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html

Streaming would definitively be a better idea than loading all of those videos. Unless there's a specific reason why you want to load them?